# in python3 the initialdir does not work on mac

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, macos-sonoma

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
def done():
    text_to_write=text.get(1.0, 'end-1c')
    file=filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir='/Users/andypukhalyk/Desktop/here', defaultextension='.txt', filetypes=(('text files', '*.txt'),('docx', '*.docx')))
    window.destroy()
    if file:
        file.write(text_to_write)
        file.close()
window = Tk()
text = Text(window)
text.pack()
Button(window, text='Save', command=done).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

when I press save button it will ask 'Save as:', 'Tags:', 'Where:' Documents -iCloud, 'Format:'... but why initial directory is Documents and not here?

when i am replacing

```
filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir='/Users/andypukhalyk/Desktop/here', defaultextension='.txt', filetypes=(('text files', '*.txt'),('docx', '*.docx')))
```

with

```
filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir='/Users/andypukhalyk/Desktop/here')
```

it works

Comment: does `/Users/andypukhalyk/Desktop/here` already exist? When I run your code and pass it a non-existing folder then I see the behavior you describe. If I pass it an existing folder name then that folder is the initial directory as expected.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, /Users/andypukhalyk/Desktop/here exists (os.path.exists('/Users/andypukhalyk/Desktop/here') returns True)

Comment: Does it exist as a directory rather than a file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an options object instead of one variable at a time

```
options = {
    'defaultextension': '.txt',
    'filetypes': [('Text files', '.txt'), ('All files', '.*')],
    'initialdir': '/Users/andypukhalyk/Desktop/here',
    'initialfile': 'MyExampleFile',
    'title': 'Save as...'
}


#Open dialog
file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', **options)
```

Comment: initialfile works but initialdir still doesn't

Comment: I can't replicate your error on Sonoma 14.1.1 (23B81). When using the options object, the dialog gets opened in the correct directory i have specified as initialdir